# To detect logoff

Tags: c#, java, .net

Is it possible to detect when a PC is logging off. I need to develop an application which writes in a text document about the logoff time, before the PC gets logged off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET see this question: [Is there a way in c# to detect a Windows shutdown/logoff and cancel that action (after asking the user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617538/is-there-a-way-in-c-to-detect-a-windows-shutdown-logoff-and-cancel-that-action)